# kendo grid Filter not pass into method

Tags: filter, kendo-ui, grid, datasource

I want to pass kendo grid DataSourceRequest to web api

my web api iS:

```
[HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetAll([FromBody] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            try
            {
                var itemList = new JsonListFormat<ItemVm>
                {
                    Data = new ItemCrud().GetItemList(request),
                    Total = new ItemCrud().GetItemTotalCount()
                };
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, itemList);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return HttpResponseController.HttpResponseException(Request, ex);
            }
        }
```

but request.Filters is always null.
for test I call my web api method with postman and this json data:

```
{
    "page": 10,
    "pageSize": 20,
    "sorts": [
        {
            "member": "Title",
            "sortDirection": 0
        }
    ],
    "filters": [
        {
            "convertedValue": "test",
            "member": "Title",
            "memberType": null,
            "operator": 2,
            "value": "test"
        }
    ],
    "groups": null,
    "aggregates": []
}
```

everything pass to request parameter but rquest.Filters is null !!!

anyone can explain what's my problem.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this option?

```
dataSource.serverFiltering = true;
```

please check [Server filtering](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/multiselect/serverfiltering)